# ProGuard doesn't generate mapping file

Tags: android, apk, proguard

I have read multiple threads on SO but couldn't find any answer. I have multiple questions here. Let me describe:

- I don't know much about ProGuard but according to my information, it obfuscates the Android code to some extent. My question is Do I need to enable it somewhere? `minifyEnabled` is `false` in my Gradle file. Does this disable ProGuard completely?
- To deobfuscate the crash on Firebase and get stack trace, I need the mapping file. I can't find it anywhere. In app/build/outputs folder, I only have

[image: Folder]

Then I read somewhere about `proguard-rules.pro` file. It just had some comments and no code. Then I put this in it: `-printmapping mapping.txt`. Then generated signed APK again, still no success. What am I missing?

Edit 1: If I have to execute some adb terminal command, please describe steps. I have never used Terminal before.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your gradle file **you must specifically set the minifyEnabled option to true.**
This enables obfuscation. By doing so, it also applies the obfuscation rules that you define on your **'proguard-rules.pro' file.**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

You can print the **mapping** and the **seeds** used (note that you need both to fully decode/understand the encrypted code) by applying the respective commands

```
-printseeds obfuscation/seeds.txt
```

and

```
-printmapping obfuscation/mapping.txt
```

An example of a basic proguard file is :

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-verbose

-dump obfuscation/class_files.txt
-printseeds obfuscation/seeds.txt
-printusage obfuscation/unused.txt
-printmapping obfuscation/mapping.txt
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I'm getting an error after enabling Proguard and generating signed apk. debug APK generates successfully though but not signed. Here's the gradle message: https://db.tt/Xhm8C10T

Comment: Im getting a bit worried about the 'can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor' examples. Seems like you should keep this code out from obfuscation. In my opinion, you should not obfuscate libraries like retrofit, okttp, etc. This is because there is no point in doing so. If the library is public, even though you obfuscate it people can still get it from their websites. You should only focus on obfuscating your property (such as your own code)

Comment: Well, you can find plenty of information all throughout stackoverflow.Try to use the -keep commands to keep the public libraries out.

Comment: Using `-printmapping` does create a mapping file but it is always empty.

Answer (score 9):

try to check setting -> InstantRun... it must be disabled :)

Comment: Got you 91 :-D Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

1. Set minifyEnabled to true.
2. Build generate APK.
3. Look in the outputs folder for mappings file.[Don't Clean Project or it will be gone]

Comment: I'm getting an error after enabling Proguard and generating signed apk. debug APK generates successfully though but not signed. Here's the gradle message: https://db.tt/Xhm8C10T

Comment: use -dontwarn flag with all the library package that you are using in your project like "-dontwarn com.android.volley.**" in proguard rules

Comment: Adding -ignorewarning worked! There shouldn't be problem with the functioning of my app, right?

Comment: you must test it out.. as much as you can. There should be no problem.

Comment: Just a little help. I have retrofit and Picasso libraries in my project. How can I exclude them from being obfuscated. I'm trying something like this: '-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }' But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to set `minifyEnabled` to true to enable `Proguard`.
2. For some libraries, you need to write some lines inside `proguard-rules.pro` to have them not obfuscated by Proguard. See "Configure ProGuard" part on this page to learn what to add for `Firebase`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: I'm getting an error after enabling Proguard and generating signed apk. debug APK generates successfully though but not signed. Here's the gradle message: https://db.tt/Xhm8C10T